# Spark dynamic date range filter specific to another tag

Tags: python, apache-spark, optimization, pyspark

I have one table that contains date ranges that correspond to the value of another column.

Say the user chooses a date range of 7 days.

Here is the Date Reference Table (which can be thought of as a static table):

```
|---------------------|-------------------|
|      UniqueID       |   ReferenceDate   |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|          124        |     Jan-1-2015    |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|          124        |     Jan-23-2015   |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|          222        |     Oct-3-2011    |
|---------------------|-------------------|
```

And I have another table with the Unique ID, a value, and a date

Date Value Table:

```
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|      UniqueID       |         Date      |        Value      |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|          124        |     Jan-1-2015    |           4       |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|          124        |     Jan-20-2015   |           5       |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|          222        |     Oct-5-2011    |           7       |
|---------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
```

How would I write an efficient filter function to filter the Date Value Table so each UniqueID, Date falls within a date range in the Date Range Table

My current code is too inefficient:

```
dateRefDF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT UniqueID, ReferenceDate FROM dateRefTable")
                        .toPandas()

valrdd = sqlContext.sql("SELECT UniqueID, Date, Value FROM valuesTable").rdd

def filterFunction(uniqueID, date, days):
    uidDF = dateRefDF.apply(lambda row:
                    row['UniqueID'] == uniqueID and
                    row['ReferenceDate'] - days <= date and
                    row['ReferenceDate'] + days >= date, axis=1)
    if uidDF.sum() > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

valrdd.filter(lambda row: filterFunction(row["UniqueID"], row["Date"], days = 7)).take(200)
```

While this code runs, it takes too long to go into production. What would be the best way to optimize it?

Comment: Do you want to use Spark for a production engine to query your tables? Spark is not build for that. I really suggest you to check other technologies to work with that. Like Cassandra and Hbase.

Comment: I think I found a way to get around using spark, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd just `join` by `UniqueId`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

dateRefDF = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(124, "Jan-1-2015"), (124, "Jan-23-2015"), (222, "Oct-3-2011")],
    ("UniqueID", "ReferenceDate")
).withColumn("ReferenceDate", to_timestamp("ReferenceDate", "MMM-dd-yyyy"))


valrdd = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(124, "Jan-1-2015", 4), (124, "Jan-20-2015", 5), (222, "Oct-5-2011", 7)],
    ("UniqueID", "Date", "Value")
).withColumn("Date", to_timestamp("Date", "MMM-dd-yyyy"))

joined = (dateRefDF               
  .join(valrdd, "UniqueId")                                                   
  .where(col("Date").between(  
     col("ReferenceDate") - expr("INTERVAL {} days".format(days)),
     col("ReferenceDate") + expr("INTERVAL {} days".format(days)))))
```

This will give:

```
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|UniqueID|      ReferenceDate|               Date|Value|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
|     222|2011-10-03 00:00:00|2011-10-05 00:00:00|    7|
|     124|2015-01-01 00:00:00|2015-01-01 00:00:00|    4|
|     124|2015-01-23 00:00:00|2015-01-20 00:00:00|    5|
+--------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+
```

You can add `broadcast` hint to the smaller `DataFrame`.

If you expect duplicates, you can:

```
joined.drop_duplicates(["UniqueID"])
```